# Refreshing subview of uiview?

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, refresh

I want to refresh the uiview which has uiimageview and uilabel as a subview of uiview.
I don't know how to do this.Plz help me out to do.

Thank u...
Renya

Answer (score 11):

For custom views, just send your view the message to refresh itself.

For **Objective-C**

```
[yourView setNeedsDisplay];
```

or

```
[yourView setNeedsDisplayInRect:aRect];
```

For **Swift**

```
yourView.setNeedsDisplay()
```

or

```
yourView.setNeedDisplay(aRect)
```

The standard views generally refresh automatically whenever you change their contents, i.e. change the text of a label or the image of an imageview.